# Ember find with or

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How do I build an ember-data findQuery that allows 'or' logic. For eg, I want to find all the records where `date1 = '2015/5/14' OR date2 = '2015/5/14'`

At the moment the only way I can do it is to make two separate find calls like:

```
this.store.find('documents', {date1: '2015/5/14'});
this.store.find('documents', {date2: '2015/5/14'});
```

when really I need to do something like:

```
this.store.find('documents', {date1: '2015/5/14'},{date:2: '2015/5/14'});
```

I'm hitting a flask-restless server that supports an 'OR' filter, I just need to know how to wire ember-data to call it correctly.

Comment: I think you can just group them like ```this.store.find('documents', {date:['2015/5/14', '2015/5/14']```

Comment: I think that's looking at multiple dates for the same property, I need to query two properties with an OR operator.